# Firefox giving SSL error message after installing new certs

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-6

Firefox users are getting the message **This connection is untrusted** when going to our [web site](https://www.idecweb.us/). under the technical details section it lists the reason as **"The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.**" We just installed new certs yesterday. Other browsers don't seem to be having this problem. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: IE11 indicates the CA isn't trusted.

Comment: @Ramhound, what are you clicking in IE to see this?

Comment: I click on the red icon that is shown when the IE determines there is a problem with the secure connection.  I can confirm the CA used isn't trusted by the computer I am working on ( by default ).  Firefox uses its own certificate store.  Chrome and IE uses the OS certificate store.

Comment: Check this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-untrusted-error-message can get you with some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [report from ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.idecweb.us&s=140.254.48.186&latest) you are missing chain certificates. This way browsers which do not have the missing intermediates certificates cached and which don't download them can not verify the certificate chain.

Apart from that you better make lots of improvements for this site:

- SSLv3 is still enabled (broken)
- RC4-MD5 as preferred cipher (weak)